# Can this question on Autism/Asperger's Syndrome be reopened?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [What are the pros and cons of disclosing a spectrum disorder when applying for a job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2163/3192) was closed as "not constructive" about 4 years ago because it asked for "pros and cons". However, much water has flown under the bridge, and we have accepted more "subjective" questions since then.

In particular, this closely related question [I'm not being hired, presumably because I have Asperger's. Is there anything I can do about it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27116/3192) seems to have been received more positively. More recently, we also got this question [Should I mention that I'm autistic in an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77004/3192) which seems to be an exact duplicate of the closed question.

We don't even have the "not constructive" close reason any more. Can the question be considered for reopening? If not, can it be edited to make it reopenable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have significantly edited the question for language and to get rid of the typical "advice question" components (*"should I?", "what's best?"*). The question is fine for our current standards and is answerable. **I've voted to reopen.**

I've also merged the *aspergers* and *autism* tags into the [autism-spectrum](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism-spectrum) tag since that adequately covers both and helps to group these questions together.

Comment: Nice, thanks. :)

Comment: That tag merger will probably aggravate a good deal many people with Asperger's Syndrome.  Just a heads up.  It's a touchy subject.

Comment: @RichardU It's the correct term as per DSM-V. It's not the only touchy subject we deal with on this site and if people want to complain they can contact the American Psychiatric Association that created these definitions. :)

Comment: @Lilienthal The APA has gotten a good deal of heat from the change from the DSM-IV to the DSM-V and the declassification of AS as a disorder and rolling it into PDD umbrella as ASD.  I'm not one of those people with an axe to grind, just letting you know that they're out there.  As for me, you can call me anything so long as you don't call me late for dinner.

Comment: @RichardU Fair, I'll keep it in mind. :)